# Is analytic geometry unique to the Cartesian plane?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I read somewhere on Stackexchange that analytic geometry referred to geometric evaluation using the coordinate system of the Cartesian plane ($ℝ^2$).  I wanted to clarify; does analytic geometry apply *exclusively* to the Cartesian plane?

Comment: Nothing in analytic geometry means the space has to be two dimensional. It is standard to talk about analytic geometry of planes and lines in 3d space.

Comment: Analytic geometry is geometry using coordinate systems, but the coordinates do not have to be Cartesian or 2-dimensional. Like pretty much every term for a field of mathematics, the boundaries of what is and isn't "Analytic geometry" are fuzzy. Where does analytic geometry stop and differential geometry, or algebraic geometry start? Both of these also depend on coordinates. Does that make them subfields of analytic geometry or not? You will probably get different answers to these questions from different mathematicians.